# Vedas said about only 4 castes based on job. Then how these much castes came

Tags: caste-system

Vedas tells about 4 casetes
Brahmin, Kshatriya, Shudra and vaishya based on jobs.

But now, there are many castes like nambissan, namboodiri, thiyya, nair, etc. etc.

How this splitted?

Comment: Vedas only talk about Varna. Caste (Kula) or race (Jati) is man made. Four Varnas are Brahmana, kshatriya, Vaishya and Sudra. There are debates that varna is Guna (quality) based only and birth based only and both in accordance. You can check questions and answers under [tag:caste-system].

Comment: Caste is not based on job according to saastra. It is based on guna+karma accumulated over all the lifetimes of that particular jeeva.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, i don't think anyone argues that varna is based on BIRTH ONLY. There are a hundred different reasons why someone can fall from brahmana to shudra, in a few minutes even (just drink some beer is enough)

Comment: @TheDestroyer, but when people argue that it is GUNA ONLY, they're basically misleading 99.9% of people, who have no idea of the huge amount of tapas required to 'upgrade' varna.. at minimum, can they give up meat, alcohol, gambling etc. let alone fast or do sandhya? nowadays even 'brahmins' cannot do that.